# Crontab not running all @reboot services

Tags: cron

In my raspberry I'm using the following crontab to start two services at startup. The first one works fine but the second one doesn't (even though it works fine when I launch it manually). Any suggestions what could be causing this are highly appreciated.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 * * * * python pythonprojects/temperature_sensor/read_temperature.py
@reboot             sudo /usr/local/bin/pigpiod
@reboot             sudo /usr/bin/autossh -M 20005 -N -T -R22222:localhost:22 -i ssh-ec2/ec-key.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `sudo` and have this

- directly in `root`'s crontab or
- in `/etc/crontab` having the user set to `root`

  ```
  @reboot   root   command parameters
  ```

Cron is not able to interactively ask for sudoer's password.

Comment: If i do it with root; i assume it will ask some confirmation message the first time I connect. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Not sure sudo is the problem because it works with the first line

Comment: With `sudo` you are already trying to run it as root. It's just not the correct way to do that.

Comment: tried it but doesn't work

Comment: How can I debug this. is there a log for what happens then @reboot of crontab is launched?